# Append-only server performance

Tags: append, zeromq

I'm building a small web server for learning purposes.

For each incoming POST request I'm planning to append the content to a file.

- I'm using ZeroMQ sockets for communicating with the file-append process. Do I need to take special care with the file operations (fopen, fseek)?
- Considering a typical Amazon EC2 instance and that each request has at most 1kb, how many file-append operations per second can my server handle?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the definition of typical? small or micro or medium?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic concerns should be followed, what happens if multiple processes are run and receive messages.  What happens if you run out of disk space or a write fails?

Are you after synchronous writing to disk or is buffered, and potential of log corruption, acceptable?  `fopen` and friends are buffered, consider `open` and friends for non-buffered writes.

Performance is tied to whether you can batch writes, use buffering, or want synchronous writes to disk.  I think Amazon provide some IOPS details, certainly other developers have published results:

http://www.thebitsource.com/featured-posts/rackspace-cloud-servers-versus-amazon-ec2-performance-analysis/

http://blog.dt.org/index.php/2010/06/amazon-ec2-io-performance-local-emphemeral-disks-vs-raid0-striped-ebs-volumes/

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=132387